# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect,Launch canceled

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run android app from eclipse . I have connected a device to pc . When I am trying to run the apps , it shows me the following error .

```
[2015-09-09 17:35:47 - amtob] Failed to install amtob.apk on device 'QS7SJBG64LL7I7IN': Connection refused: connect
[2015-09-09 17:35:47 - amtob] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2015-09-09 17:35:47 - amtob] Launch canceled!
```

What is error ? How can I solve them ?

Comment: Just plug-out the device and plug-in and try.

Comment: Same problem arises .

Comment: It is the problem in the connection between device and computer. Try changing the usb cable.

Comment: Maybe your device isnt enabled to accept running apps from eclipse. YOu need to enable it in the device settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the problem in the connection between device and computer. Try changing the usb cable or restart the eclipse.